# Nginx configs for Dynatrace

Tags: nginx, dynatrace

- nginx version: nginx/1.12.1
- Dynatrace version: 7.0
- uname -a ==> Linux
  xxx.elinux.xxx 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP
  Sat Sep 9 03:55:24 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have been trying to get nginx metrics being sent across to Dynatrace without success.

When I start nginx, the dynatrace agent logs show -

```
2017-10-31 21:58:14 [ce68772b] info    [native] Successfully loaded agent binary /opt/dynatrace/agent/downloads/appmon/native/7.0.8.1014/linux-x86-64/libdtnginxagent.so

==> dt_dtnginxagent_w1b-dev-et-rz-app-bb-web_26779.0.log <==
2017-10-31 21:58:19.808088 [26779/ce68772b] warning [native] generate_offsets.sh script generated
2017-10-31 21:58:19.808181 [26779/ce68772b] warning [native] Automatic Nginx agent configuration generation failed
2017-10-31 21:58:19.808192 [26779/ce68772b] warning [native] In order to run Nginx with dynaTrace Agent you need to perform this manual step:
2017-10-31 21:58:19.808199 [26779/ce68772b] warning [native] Please run the following command to generate Nginx Agent configuration and then restart Nginx:
2017-10-31 21:58:19.808208 [26779/ce68772b] warning [native] /opt/dynatrace/agent/conf/generate_offsets.sh -b /usr/sbin/nginx -o /opt/dynatrace/agent/conf/dtnginx_self_generated_offsets.json

2017-10-31 22:23:39.474132 [26751/b77f98d5] info    [native] New subAgent registered successfully: db846b2b
2017-10-31 22:23:39.485625 [26751/b77f98d5] info    [native] sub agent registered with id (sub/slave) db846b2b/dedfe76e9 (UDP queue size: 0)
2017-10-31 22:23:45.090885 [26751/b77f98d5] info    [native] New subAgent registered successfully: b805cd43
2017-10-31 22:23:45.090913 [26751/b77f98d5] info    [native] sub agent registered with id (sub/slave) b805cd43/d8ec7151e (UDP queue size: 0)
2017-10-31 22:23:52.102050 [26751/c69d78d5] info    [native] License update received for sub agent db846b2b: license = ok, uem volume = not exhausted
2017-10-31 22:23:52.102104 [26751/c69d78d5] info    [native] Subagent license is updated, id=[0xdb846b2b] = license ok;

2017-10-31 22:23:52.114657 [26751/c69d78d5] info    [native] License update received for sub agent b805cd43: license = ok, uem volume = not exhausted
2017-10-31 22:23:52.114689 [26751/c69d78d5] info    [native] Subagent license is updated, id=[0xb805cd43] = license ok;

2017-10-31 22:23:59.099111 [26751/c8c0f895] info    [native] Unregistering subAgent db846b2b
2017-10-31 22:23:59.099191 [26751/c8c0f895] info    [native] sub agent unregistered with id (sub/slave) db846b2b/dedfe76e9 (UDP queue size: 0)
2017-10-31 22:24:05.106795 [26751/c8c0f895] info    [native] Unregistering subAgent b805cd43
2017-10-31 22:24:05.106863 [26751/c8c0f895] info    [native] sub agent unregistered with id (sub/slave) b805cd43/d8ec7151e (UDP queue size: 0)
```

As per the documentation, I have updated the '/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service' file as follows -

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=http://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
Environment=LD_PRELOAD=/opt/dynatrace/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -p /opt/log/nginx
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -p /opt/log/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see the Agent in the AppMon Client in the Agent Overview? Did you see the "warn" entries about manually regenerating offsets in the logs? Did you do these steps?

Comment: Have you generated the offset file with `/opt/dynatrace/agent/conf/generate_offsets.sh -b /usr/sbin/nginx -/opt/dynatrace/agent/conf/dtnginx_self_generated_offsets.json`?